# 100% of remaining space after setting a fixed header

Tags: css, reactjs

I'm trying to layout my small React project.
Here's the link to codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/szkola-reacta-44-kalkulator-wydatkow-rvh5t?file=/src/styles.css

What I want to achieve is login page, which will (after login) show expenses and incomes. I want to content below header to occupy the whole remaining space, but the whole page shouldn't be scrollable. I've tried two approaches:

1. Firstly I've set width of 100vh to an App component, then I've set .main to 100%, to occupy the rest of remaining space after setting up the header. I've found out that it'll set 100vh as well, so it'll be scrollable and I don't want it to be.
2. Secondly I've made a header fixed, but then my whole form isn't centered, because header isn't in the document flow.

I prefere to find solution for the first approach, in the second one I know I can calc it somehow (but I need guidance), however the first one looks more straightforward for me, but I'm missing something.

In general, no matter how, but I want to have a header, which will be always in the same place, a dynamically changing content which will occupy remaining space and the whole app should occupy 100vh to prevent from scrolling.

Comment: If you can share demo login creds, anyone can check it out, your login page looks fine, it's not scrollable

Comment: I can confirm that currently it's not scrollable and your approach with (100% - 9rem) is a good approach and it should be working as intended.

Comment: You can also only used flex/grid to avoid calc() and position. here an example https://codesandbox.io/s/szkola-reacta-44-kalkulator-wydatkow-forked-xqhh4 . grid is used for the form, so the content is centered as a single column. header cannot overlap anymore the form if you shrink down the window.

Comment: @kiran it's a fake login, just write anything.

Comment: @PCPbiscuit yeah, I've tried this approach, but I was wondering if there's a way to not set fixed height on the header

Comment: @G-Cyrillus it was already positioned with flexbox (and I've tried with grid as well), but without setting fixed height of header it still was scrollable :/ I forgot that I share version wich I edit, so at the time you've seen, I've already set fixed height of the header. Anyway, thanks all for the answers! <3